# Extraction of XML node values via SQL cursor compatibility issue

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure which accepts a XMLdocument from a C# function.  A sample of the output of the XML file is below:

```
<roots>
  <root>
    <AnalyteCode>CCBILID   </AnalyteCode>
    <InstrumentID>1483</InstrumentID>
    <IsSD>1</IsSD>
    <IsSEM>0</IsSEM>
    <Level1IntraPrecision>3.00</Level1IntraPrecision>
    <Level2IntraPrecision>5.00</Level2IntraPrecision>
    <Level3IntraPrecision>6.00</Level3IntraPrecision>
    <IsUpdated>1</IsUpdated>
  </root>
</roots>
```

The SP accepts a variable of type XML and I have setup a cursor to iterate over the nodes and extract the relevant attributes stored within.

Note: Code within the cursor iterations would be replaced with update/insert statements depending on whether or not the current node already exists in the designated table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RDX_SaveUncertaintyMeasurementReportOptions] 
@OptionsXml XML,
@ParticipantID INT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
  SET ARITHABORT OFF

-- variables used to cursor through all XML nodes
DECLARE @id INT, -- id of any existing report options
      @analyte_code NCHAR(10), 
      @instrument_id INT, 
      @is_sd BIT,
      @is_sem BIT,
      @level_1_intra NUMERIC(10, 4),
      @level_2_intra NUMERIC(10, 4),
      @level_3_intra NUMERIC(10, 4);

-- setup cursor over all nodes within XML file
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT tab.col.value('AnalyteCode[1]','NCHAR(10)') as analyte_code,
      tab.col.value('InstrumentID[1]','INT') as instrument_id,
      tab.col.value('IsSD[1]','BIT') as is_sd,
      tab.col.value('IsSEM[1]','BIT') as is_sem,
      tab.col.value('Level1IntraPrecision[1]','NUMERIC(10, 4)') as level_1_intra,
      tab.col.value('Level2IntraPrecision[1]','NUMERIC(10, 4)') as level_2_intra,
      tab.col.value('Level3IntraPrecision[1]','NUMERIC(10, 4)') as level_3_intra
 FROM @OptionsXml.nodes('/roots/root') AS tab(col)

 OPEN cur

FETCH 
 NEXT 
 FROM cur

INTO @analyte_code, 
      @instrument_id, 
      @is_sd, 
      @is_sem, 
      @level_1_intra, 
      @level_2_intra, 
      @level_3_intra

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- Update/insert code would be here, replaced with selects for testing
SELECT @analyte_code, 
@instrument_id, 
@is_sd, 
@is_sem, 
@level_1_intra, 
@level_2_intra, 
@level_3_intra
END

CLOSE cur;

DEALLOCATE cur;
END
```

The issue is that this code works perfectly with with my development environment SSMS version (2014), however when deploying to our servers currently using SSMS 2008 R2, the XML extraction highlights the following error:

> Cannot find either column "tab" or the user defined function or aggregate "tab.col.value", or the name is ambiguous.

I have attached two images - one of the 'no error' SSMS 2014 and one of the above error being displayed on SSMS 2008.

[SSMS 2008](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaW3O.png)

[SSMS 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNPXg.png)

Of course the easiest way to combat the issue may be to update the deployment SSMS to 2014 however this is not possible.  Does anyone know why this compatibility issue exists and/or could suggest a suitable alternative to perform the same actions?  Any help would be greatly appreciated for someone who is at their wits end with this one......

Comment: Does the code actually give that error when executing? It's immaterial what error SSMS gives on syntax highlighting; what matters is how the server executes the code.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @Jeroen.  The SP can be created/altered successfully however during SP execution, a SqlException is thrown as follows -  `SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.`

Comment: You're creating the procedure wrong, then. Add `SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` before `CREATE PROCEDURE` and try again. These options are locked in when the stored procedure is created, not when it's executed.

Comment: I would never have thought of looking for that!! Thank you so much, saved a lot more time wasting at this end.  On a side-note, and after further investigation, it looks like Visual Studio schema-compare reversed the values assigned to both of the above attributes i.e. during the update it turned `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFER` to off.

Comment: That's possibly a bug, but one possible cause is that your database isn't using the same defaults for these options between servers. From Management Studio, check the database properties and then "options". You should have "ANSI NULLS Enabled" on "True" and "Quoted Identifiers Enabled" on "True". Even though applications should really set these options themselves so the defaults shouldn't matter, every so often they still do.